# Make object disappear when it leaves specific camera viewport in VR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

I searched around for different solutions to make an object disappear when it leaves a specific camera viewport in VR.

I ended up using following solution using GeometryUtility:

```
        //Create camera planes
        Plane[] planes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes(Camera.main);
        //Check if object renderer is in camera view
        if (!GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB(planes, GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds))
        {
            //Condition waiting for 2nd object to spawn (To avoid object 1 doesn't disappear instantly)
            if (objectCondition.activeSelf)
            {
                //Deactivate object
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
```

However this results in the object to disappear before it is out of the viewport (Around halfway out, instead of all the way). Am I implementing this wrong, or is it simply a VR issue?

Comment: You set right your bounds? the script is in your current gameobject to be disabled? this gameobject have a collider?

Answer (score 0):

You could either use `Renderer.isVisible`, or `Renderer.OnBecameVisible()` and `Renderer.OnBecameInvisible()`

The below example is from the manual pages.

Enabled does not disable the GameObject though, it just "suspends" updates if the object is not seen by any Camera. If you use Coroutines you will need to pause them yourself.

Obviously, since this method uses the renderer, you cant just disable the GameObject. I mean you could, but it would not re-enable by OnBecameVisible. But Objects outside the camera frustum dont get renderd/get culled anyway.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    void OnBecameInvisible() {
        enabled = false;
    }
    void OnBecameVisible() {
        enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it take ALL cameras into account right? Including editor, I really want a method where I can specify this for just one camera.

Comment: Hey @JonDier did you find out how to do it?